# The task of displaying numbers

Tags: c++

Can't complete the task and need your help. With single digits all OK, but when i trying numbers like 9865, output is wrong.

Task:

Input:

The first line contains an integer  (0 ≤  ≤ 1e6). The second line contains nine separated by a space
integers 1, 2,…, 9(1 ≤  ≤ 1e5) - the value in gold of each digit (from 1 to 9, respectively).

Output:

Print the maximum number for which the player has enough gold. The value of the number is equal to the sum of the values
each digit included in it. If the player does not have enough gold for any number, then output −1

EXAMPLE:

Input:

n = 2
a[9] = {1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 4}

Output:

11

Note:

In the example, two units of gold may only be enough for one digit 2 or two digits 1, so the maximum number that can be applied is 11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
const int MAX = 9;


int main()
{
    int a[MAX];                     // array
    int b[MAX];                     
    unsigned int n;                 // gold
    cin >> n;                       
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];               
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        int count = n / a[i];       
        int post = n % a[i];        
        if (count == 0)
        {
            b[i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
            {
                if (post == 0)
                {
                    string prom = to_string(a[i]);      // int to string
                    if (count > 1)
                    {
                        prom += to_string(a[i]);
                    }
                    b[i] = atoi(prom.c_str());          // string to int
                }
                else
                {
                    string prom = to_string(a[i]);      // int to string
                    if (count > 1)
                    {
                        prom += to_string(a[i]) + to_string(post);
                    }
                    b[i] = atoi(prom.c_str());          // string to int
                }

            }
        }
    }
    int maxnum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (b[i] > maxnum)
        {
            maxnum = b[i];
        }
    }
    cout << maxnum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how the algorithm you've chosen is related to the problem being solved. There's nothing to be fixed in this code, I would start again.

Comment: It doesn't work correctly with all single digits either. (Say you have nine gold, and all digits cost three. The largest number you can buy is 999, but your program says it's 33.) Go back to the drawing board.

Comment: I think that one of the reasons for your problems is that you’re confusing the digits with the prices of the digits.